# Continuous loop while scanning a XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, loops, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to make a program that reads a selected XML file which another program write its now playing song and artist to at the start of each song.

This is what I've got so far but I need the code to loop continuously so that when a new song is automatically loaded and the XML file is edited it will update on here as well.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml

Public Class MainForm

'Variables Declared'

'Saves file path as path'
Public XMLPath As String
'Full path to selected file'
Dim Path As String = Me.XMLPath

Private Sub LoadXMLButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadXML_Button.Click

    'Filehandle to to open dialog
    Dim XMLPathFileHandle As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog

    'Title of dialog box
    XMLPathFileHandle.Title = "Select XML file"

    'File types which file dialog accepts
    XMLPathFileHandle.Filter = "All files (*.xml)|*.xml"

    'if user clicks ok
    If XMLPathFileHandle.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        'save selected file path
        XMLPath = XMLPathFileHandle.FileName

        'show file path in combobox
        ComboBox1.Text = XMLPath

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub StartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click

        'check if file exists
        If (IO.File.Exists(XMLPath)) Then

            'create a new xmltextreader object
            'this is the object that we will loop and will be used to read the xml file
            Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(XMLPath)

            'loop through the xml file
            While (document.Read())

                Dim type = document.NodeType

                'if node type was element
                If (type = XmlNodeType.Element) Then

                    'if the loop found a <ARTIST> tag
                    If (document.Name = "ARTIST") Then

                        TextBox1.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                    End If

                    'if the loop found a <TITLE> tag
                    If (document.Name = "TITLE") Then

                        TextBox2.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                    End If

                End If

            End While

            'close XML to avoid error with saving
            document.Close()

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("The filename you selected was not found.")

        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You might be better off using the `FileSystemWatcher` class so that your program can be notified when the file has been modified. That way you don't need to keep polling to check for changes.

Comment: Ah right, do you know of any good tutorials explaining how to use the FileSystemWatcher? I'm pretty new to programming so I'm not great with everything.

Answer (score -1):

example code

**-First a FileSystemWatcher Add (from toolbox)**

```
   Imports System
```

Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

```
'Variables Declared'

Dim XMLPath, Path_filename, Path_url As String



Private Sub LoadXMLButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadXML_Button.Click

    'Filehandle to to open dialog
    Dim XMLPathFileHandle As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog

    'Title of dialog box
    XMLPathFileHandle.Title = "Select XML file"

    'File types which file dialog accepts
    XMLPathFileHandle.Filter = "All files (*.xml)|*.xml"

    'if user clicks ok
    If XMLPathFileHandle.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        'save selected file path
        XMLPath = XMLPathFileHandle.FileName

        'show file path in combobox
        XMLdirectory.Text = XMLPath


        Dim filePath As String = XMLPathFileHandle.FileName
        Dim directoryPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)

        Path_url = directoryPath
        Path_filename = XMLPathFileHandle.SafeFileName


        ''********* ADD THIS AREA
        FileSystemWatcher1.Path = Path_url

        ''For file watch start
        FileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        ''*******************************
    End If

End Sub



' Add a FileSystemWatcher object from toolbox

Private Sub FileSystemWatcher1_Changed(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles FileSystemWatcher1.Changed
    TextBox1.Text = " file changed "

    'processs()


End Sub

Private Sub processs()
    Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(XMLPath)
    'check if file exists
    If (IO.File.Exists(XMLPath)) Then

        Dim type = document.NodeType

        'if node type was element
        If (type = XmlNodeType.Element) Then

            'if the loop found a <ARTIST> tag
            If (document.Name = "ARTIST") Then
                TextBox1.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()
            End If

            'if the loop found a <TITLE> tag
            If (document.Name = "TITLE") Then
                TextBox2.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()
            End If

        End If
        'close XML to avoid error with saving
        document.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Is it true I think you want it? Try it. If you have a problem, I 'll check .

**This is runnig code**

Comment: @YucelSolmaz Thank you so much for your reply, I was unable to give it a test because it keeps saying that 'document' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. when I go to open the program and the program is debugged.

Comment: Yes, I found errors. I changed the code. Try now please.

Comment: @YucelSolmaz I just gave that a try and it it now says "handles clause requires a withevents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types" on "Handles LoadXMLButton.click" on the line that looks like this -  Private Sub LoadXMLButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadXMLButton.Click '*** Thats true (sorry to be a pain hope you know the fix)

Comment: Does it work this way?
"Private Sub LoadXMLButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadXML_Button.Click"

Comment: If you change the name if it can work as well . You need to try both way.

Comment: @YucelSolmaz Thats cleared all the syntax errors so were getting closer slowly, now another error :( it says this: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Now Playing Shoutcast Uploader.exe

Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: url

Comment: When giving this error? Is giving this error when the project started?

Comment: @PerryNewman give me example xml document's code.Is there anything else in the project?

Comment: @YucelSolmaz Would it be easier for me to upload the source file along with the XML to my dropbox?

Comment: @YucelSolmaz https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rn7a9nzp7n2k7df/AAArzYHfHRekm1I_iKxKA5Ksa?dl=0 the XML file is in there along with the source files just incase

Comment: @YucelSolmaz no problem, if you find the problem just upload the code on here and I'll update it this end

Comment: Problem this code : 'Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(XMLPath)'
but why am I trying to figure it out ...

Comment: Yeeees! I understand. When project starting "XMLPath" is trying to take a value but can not get! All problem this is

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work it shows a weird word in the first textbook when the xml file is updated? What the program is supposed to do is scan an XML file for two tags <ARTIST>  and <TITLE> it's then suppose to update the two current playing song text boxes on the form when the song is updated in the XML file and do that continuously  until the stop button is pressed (all this should happen when the START button is pressed)